# Sharp image resize in php and why it differs from result in browser (<img />)

Tags: php

**How to downscale image in php so that result is sharp?** I have tried imagecopyresampled, but result is very blurry.
If I'm changing width on image in browser by adjusting width attribute on img tag, result is very appealing. Is there any way to get same effect with php?

*Update*

Looks like I can achieve what I desire if I make icon larger than what I will actually display.

Sample: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0AiLUT or http://pastebin.com/V0PqCMpg

Comment: May i suggest that you consider using a PHP image editing library for doing this. It can save time and should work. There are many for PHP. I found this: [PHP Image Magician is an open source project that uses PHP GD to perform image manipulation in an easy, succinct way](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/). The install looks easy as does using it. I have used a few of these libraries they are all work fine.

Comment: @RyanVincent I have tried your suggested lib, but quality does not seem to change.

Comment: Please post a link to your image and what size and output format you want it. Please  edit your question to show the code that you are using to generate the 'downscale images'. I assure you that that 'GD' is fine for making reasonable quality 'thumbnail' images.

Comment: Yes, it is fine, but I would like to get closer result to that what browser displays when image width or height is reduced. One workaround would be to create icon larger than it will actually be displayed. I will update my q.